# Change in a quantity described by a dot product

Tags: vectors, rotations

In the Rotations section of Arfken's chapter on vector analysis in the book "Mathematical Methods for Physicists", there is a statement which says the following -

> The dot product is the projection of $\bf{e_{u'}}$ onto the $\bf{e_v}$
>   direction and is therefore the change in $x_v$ that is produced by a
>   unit change in $x_{u'}$.

Although it sounds very trivial, and it probably is, I am unable to understand this statement clearly. Can someone explain why the statement is true?

For reference, this statement is on page 139 in the 7th edition of the book.

Edit: $e_{u^\prime}\cdot e_v$ is the dot product involved

Comment: Can you clarify what $x_v$ and $x_{u'}$ are? Are these coordinate functions with respect to particular bases? Orthonormal bases?

Comment: Also, can you include which dot product is being discussed? For example, is it $e_{u^\prime}\cdot e_v$?

Comment: @NathanielMayer, the prime represents a rotated coordinate system. The rest of what you said is correct

Comment: if you add 1 (a unit) to $x_{u'}$ then $x_{v}$ changes by ${\bf e}_{u'}\cdot{\bf e}_{v}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e_{v_1}, ... e_{v_n}$ be an orthogonal basis, and $x_{v_i}$ the coordinate functions so that any vector $w$ decomposes as
$$w = \sum_{i=1}^n x_{v_i}(w) e_{v_i}.$$
Take a dot product of both sides with a basis vector $e_{v_i}$ and use orthogonality to see that
$$x_{v_i}(w) = w \cdot e_{v_i}. \tag{$*$} $$

The quote you gave is articulating
$$x_{v_i}(w + e_{u'}) = x_{v_i}(w) + e_{u'} \cdot e_{v_i},$$
which follows immediately from $(*)$ above.